# Can you switch the order of hom for simple modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $A$ and $B$ be $R$-modules. Suppose that $A$ is simple.

Is it true that $$\mathrm{Hom}_R(A, B) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_R(B, A),$$

1. if we assume that $B$ is semisimple, or
2. in general?

Edit: I wanted to assume that $B$ is finitely-generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is simple, then $\hom(A,B)$ is the sum of all submodules of isomorphic to $A$ in $B$, while $\hom(B,A)$ is isomorphic to the dual in some sense (as $\operatorname{End}_R(A)$-vector spaces) of the sum of all submodules of $B/\operatorname{rad}(B)$ that are isomorphic to $A$.

To find an example where these two differ, we need a module $B$ whose socle and top (that is, $B/\operatorname{rad}({B})$) have different number of copies of $A$.

Let $k$ be a field, let $R=k\langle x,y\rangle$ be the free algebra with two generators, and let $B$ be the $R$-module with $k$-basis $\{a,b,c\}$ such that $$x\cdot a=b, \quad x\cdot b=x\cdot c=0, \quad y\cdot a=c, \quad y\cdot b=y\cdot c=0.$$

On the othert hand, let $A=R/(x,y)$ be the $1$-dimensional module on which $x$ and $y$ act by zero.

With these choices $\hom(A,B)$ has dimension $2$ and $\hom(B,A)$ has dimension $1$.

If you want a finite dimensional algebra $R$, replace $R$ by $R/(x^2,xy,yx,y^2)$, which is even commutative.

Comment: What do you mean by "the sum of all submodules of $A$ in $B$"? Isn't $A$ simple and therefore have no submodules?

Answer (score 1):

Answer: No.
Let $k$ be a field, and $V$ an infinite-dimensional $k$-vector space. Then, as $k$-vector spaces, $k$ is simple, $V$ is semisimple, and $$\text{Hom}_k(k,V) \cong V \not\cong V^\vee := \text{Hom}_k(V,k).$$

**Edit:** If $B$ is finitely generated and semisimple, then this is true.
Why? Being semisimple and finitely generated, then is a *finite* direct sum of simple modules: $B \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^n S_i$. Thus
$$
\text{Hom}_R(A,B) \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^n \text{Hom}_R(A,S_i), \\
\text{Hom}_R(B,A) \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^n \text{Hom}_R(S_i,A).
$$
And since $\text{Hom}_R(A,S_i) \cong \text{Hom}_R(S_i,A)$ (if $A \not\cong S_i$, then both sides are zero) for each $i$, it follows that $\text{Hom}_R(A,B) \cong \text{Hom}_R(B,A)$.

Comment: What if $B$ is finitely-generated?

Comment: What I was thinking is that if $B$ is semisimple then $$B = \bigoplus_{M \text{ simple}} n_M M$$ so the dimension of $\mathrm{Hom}_R(A, B)$ and $\mathrm{Hom}_R(B, A)$ are both just $n_A$ right?

Comment: @lagomorphism I have updated my answer :)